# Implicit intent to open waze or google and then start navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, waze

This is the thing I want to achieve: I have the LatLng object. The user clicks the button, it will let user to choose waze or googlemap to navigate
(if the user only have one of them, just go into the app and start navigation)(if the have Waze and googlemap app, show to the user and there also need have the options: Just once and set default. Then the user clicks the button, it will go the that specific navigation app directly and start navigation)
I know how to create an intent for one of them, but don't know to create an implicit intent for showing up two of them. Please help me thanks.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    LatLng location= new LatLng(34,118); // just for example

    String urlWaze = "https://waze.com/ul?ll="+location.latitude+","+location.longitude;
    Intent intentWaze = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlWaze));
    intentWaze.setPackage("com.waze");

    String uriGoogle = "google.navigation:q=" + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude;
    Intent intentGoogleNav = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriGoogle));
    intentGoogleNav.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [App Chooser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser), but if you start other app from your application, you can show standard or custom [`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) with chooser, and make `intentWaze` or `intentGoogleNav` on user response.

Comment: According to android API, chooser can't have default app, which means users have to choose every time.

Comment: Anyway, you can show custom Dialog with chooser, process user choice in your application, save result in Perferences and then start Google Maps or Waze.